# How to Create Nested Tab Windows in NetBeans Platform

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I'm building an application with the NetBeans Platform, and I'm trying to create nested NetBeans tab groups, as shown in the following mock-up:

[Nested Tabs Mockup](http://tinypic.com/r/2njlz4g/5)

I know that I can create a Tabbed Pane, but Tabbed Panes don't have the level of flexibility that NetBeans tabs do (rearrange tab orders, tear away tabs, etc.).  I want to use NetBeans tabs at all levels of nesting in my application.  However, despite hours searching online, I have not found a way to implement this either through the Matisse builder or through Swing coding.

I would appreciate any advice anybody could provide.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to learn more about tabs in Nb platform, this [blog page](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/farewell_to_space_consuming_weird) could help you for what you look for.